# Delegate(?) action events

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action

I'd like to give my app users a reward after they've successfully watched a chartboost ad video, but the problem is that I can't add a function to it.

Here's the line of code in the script:

```
public static event Action<CBLocation,int> didCompleteRewardedVideo;
```

Now I have no knowledge about event actions, So I thought this piece of code would do:

```
Chartboost.didCompleteRewardedVideo += new EventHandler(DidCompleteRewardedVideo);
```

And he function:

```
public void DidCompleteRewardedVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Energy", 10);
        energy = 10;
        energyText.text = energy.ToString();
    }
```

But got a compile error saying they don't match. An eventHandler is probably not the same as an action event, but just to show you how I think this works.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whe you subscribe to the event, you have to match the event signature:

```
public void DidCompleteRewardedVideo(CBLocation location, int x)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Energy", 10);
    energy = 10;
    energyText.text = energy.ToString();
}
```

Subscribe like this:

```
Chartboost.didCompleteRewardedVideo += DidCompleteRewardedVideo;
```